# Dygraph with gaps only works with rollPeriod = 1

Tags: dygraphs

I am facing the following issue using dygraph. I show multiple graphs, most of them only have one series and I want them to show gaps instead of connecting the gaps edges. 
This works fine, until I change the "rollPeriod" option. When I do so, no error occurs but the graphs become invisible, meaning the data points show up when I move the mouse over the graph but the graph itself is invisible.

Here are my dygraph options:

```
labelsDivStyles: { 'backgroundColor': 'transparent','textAlign': 'right' },
labelsSeparateLines: true,
digitsAfterDecimal: 4,
drawGapPoints: true,
fillGraph : true,
strokeWidth: 3,
axisLabelFont: "Open Sans",
xAxisLabelWidth : "60",
rollPeriod: 3,
showRangeSelector: true,
rangeSelectorHeight: 30,
rangeSelectorPlotStrokeColor: '#617e2b',
rangeSelectorPlotFillColor: '#414a4c',
pixelsPerLabel : 60,
labelsKMG2: true,
axes : {
    x: {
        valueFormatter: function(d) {
            return xAxisFormat(d);
        }
    },
    y: {
        ticker: Dygraph.numericLinearTicks
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help, i run out of ideas.

Comment: Please provide a full example using dygraphs.com/fiddle. It's hard to help you with this without seeing what your data looks like.

Comment: mmh, it seems that i somehow got rid of the problem. i cant reproduce it anymore, thanks anyway

Comment: WAIT! I am having the same problem now. :) Any idea what you changed? Any value > 1 makes the graph disappear.