# Why does showRoller on dygraphs fail with rollPeriod > 1

Tags: dygraphs

This question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22043806/dygraph-with-gaps-only-works-with-rollperiod-1) but never answered. When I add showRoller:true to my code and then set it for anything greater than 1, the graph disappears and only the very first point at the left edge is drawn.

Here is my code:

```
        g[gnum] = new Dygraph(document.getElementById(gdiv), mylines, {
            rollPeriod: 1,
            showRoller: true,
            labels: mylabels,
            drawXAxis: true,
            drawYAxis: true,
            drawXGrid: true,
            drawYGrid: true,
            valueRange: myrange,
            ylabel: ylabel[gnum],
            fillGraph: false,
            labelsShowZeroValues: true,
            highlightCircleSize: 0,
            strokeWidth: 0.4,
            gridLineColor: '#dedede',
            axisLabelColor: '#999999',
            colors: colors,
            rightGap: 15,
            highlightSeriesBackgroundAlpha: .6,
            highlightSeriesOpts: {
                strokeWidth: 0.5,
                strokeBorderWidth: 1,
                strokeBorderColor: "#6699ff",
                highlightCircleSize: 4
            },
            labelsDivWidth: 300,
            labelsDivStyles: {
                'text-align': 'right'
            },
            xAxisLabelWidth: 70,
            axisLabelFontSize: 13,
            axes: {
                x: {
                    pixelsPerLabel:80,
                    valueFormatter: function(ms) {
                        return ' ' + new Date(ms).strftime('%m/%d/%Y %T') + ' ';
                    },
                    axisLabelFormatter: function(d, gran) {
                        return Dygraph.zeropad(d.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'));
                    }
                },
                y: {
                    valueFormatter: function(y) {
                        //if (!y) return ' null ';
                        return ' ' + y + ' ' + yfmt[gnum] + ' ';
                    }
                }
            },
            drawCallback: function(me, initial) {
                var xrange = me.xAxisRange();
                if ((xrange[0] == oldxrange[0] && xrange[1] == oldxrange[1]) || blockRedraw || initial) return;
                else {
                    blockRedraw = true;
                    for (var j = 1; j <= maxGraphs; j++)
                    {
                        if (gnum == j) continue;    // don't draw if this graph or if graph doesn't exist
                        else {
                            g[j].updateOptions({
                                dateWindow: xrange
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    blockRedraw = false;
                    oldxrange = xrange;
                }
            },
            underlayCallback: function(canvas, area, g) {
                // critical threshold lines
                var bottom_left = g.toDomCoords(new Date(first[gnum]), critical[gnum][0]);
                var top_right = g.toDomCoords(new Date(last[gnum]), critical[gnum][0]);
                var left = bottom_left[0];
                var bottom = bottom_left[1];
                var right = top_right[0];
                var top = top_right[1]+5;
                canvas.fillStyle = "rgba(250, 0, 0, 1)";
                canvas.fillRect(left, bottom, right-left, 1);

                bottom_left = g.toDomCoords(new Date(first[gnum]), critical[gnum][1]);
                top_right = g.toDomCoords(new Date(last[gnum]), critical[gnum][1]);
                left = bottom_left[0];
                bottom = bottom_left[1];
                right = top_right[0];
                top = top_right[1]+5;
                canvas.fillStyle = "rgba(250, 0, 0, 1)";
                canvas.fillRect(left, bottom, right-left, 1);

                // maintenance threshold lines
                bottom_left = g.toDomCoords(new Date(first[gnum]), maintenance[gnum][0]);
                top_right = g.toDomCoords(new Date(last[gnum]), maintenance[gnum][0]);
                left = bottom_left[0];
                bottom = bottom_left[1];
                right = top_right[0];
                top = top_right[1]+5;
                canvas.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 220, 0, 1)";
                canvas.fillRect(left, bottom, right-left, 1);

                bottom_left = g.toDomCoords(new Date(first[gnum]), maintenance[gnum][1]);
                top_right = g.toDomCoords(new Date(last[gnum]), maintenance[gnum][1]);
                left = bottom_left[0];
                bottom = bottom_left[1];
                right = top_right[0];
                top = top_right[1]+5;
                canvas.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 220, 0, 1)";
                canvas.fillRect(left, bottom, right-left, 1);
            }
        });
```

I am thinking it has some conflict with one of my other parameters? When I put dygraphs sample code in my system it works fine. My data looks like this...

```
Tue Oct 04 2016 11:00:01 GMT-0700 (PDT),136.00,135.78,136.60,137.16,
Tue Oct 04 2016 17:00:01 GMT-0700 (PDT),135.89,135.89,136.56,137.19,
Tue Oct 04 2016 23:00:01 GMT-0700 (PDT),135.93,136.04,136.45,137.23,
Wed Oct 05 2016 05:00:01 GMT-0700 (PDT),135.96,136.00,136.45,137.08,
Wed Oct 05 2016 11:00:01 GMT-0700 (PDT),136.00,135.96,136.49,137.16,
Wed Oct 05 2016 17:00:01 GMT-0700 (PDT),135.96,135.96,136.52,137.12,
Wed Oct 05 2016 23:00:01 GMT-0700 (PDT),135.96,135.89,136.56,137.08,
Thu Oct 06 2016 05:00:01 GMT-0700 (PDT),136.00,135.93,136.56,137.08,
Thu Oct 06 2016 11:00:01 GMT-0700 (PDT),136.00,135.93,136.56,137.08,
Thu Oct 06 2016 11:00:07 GMT-0700 (PDT),135.81,135.78,136.45,136.90,
Thu Oct 06 2016 17:00:01 GMT-0700 (PDT),136.00,135.89,136.60,137.12,
Thu Oct 06 2016 23:00:01 GMT-0700 (PDT),136.07,135.89,136.60,137.05,
Fri Oct 07 2016 05:00:01 GMT-0700 (PDT),136.04,135.89,136.60,137.01,
Fri Oct 07 2016 11:00:01 GMT-0700 (PDT),135.96,135.89,136.52,137.19,
```

One note: there is a large gap (about 10 days) in my data? Does that matter? I would think dygraphs just calculates a lagging rolling average no matter what the dates were.

Here is the graph with roll period = 1
[image]

And here it is with roll period = 2
[image]

Note that the points are still active on the graph with roll period = 2. I can mouse over and see the data in the top right. But the lines are not drawn. What can cause this?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, preferably a before and after via dygraphs.com/fiddle.

Comment: That's a very complex thing. The entire js call is above. What else do I need? Will a large gap in data cause the problem.

Comment: My problem is it is very complex, as I have data coming in for trend lines, variable use, etc. My question is what KINDS of things can cause it not to work?

Comment: There are lots of little details that only come through in a self-contained reproduction. The roller doesn't care about the size of gaps.

Comment: OK. I'll try to get a demo set today. Thanks.

Comment: BTW Dan, the newest version throws this error with the latest chrome...

e.toExponential is not a function

dygraph-combined.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: e.toExponential is not a function(…)t.numberValueFormatter @ dygraph-combined.js:2t.generateLegendHTML @ dygraph-combined.js:5t.select @ dygraph-combined.js:5t.cascadeEvents_ @ dygraph-combined.js:2t.updateSelection_ @ dygraph-combined.js:3t.setSelection @ dygraph-combined.js:3t.mouseMove_ @ dygraph-combined.js:3mouseMoveHandler_ @ dygraph-combined.js:2

Comment: I pasted the above data into one of your fiddles and it worked. When I do it with my code, it doesn't. Now, the fiddle data is hard-coded and I am loading from a datafile, perhaps that is it? But if the date format was wrong, then the rollPeriod=1 wouldn't work. I have minimized my g=dygraphs call to do nothing but the roller and it doesn't work in my code. But it works in your fiddle. I say your fiddle because I could not get a jsfiddle to draw a graph. But your example works fine.

Comment: This is driving me nuts. It isn't the data. It isn't my dygraphs code because I removed everything from the above code except for the showRoller:true. Is there a list somewhere that would suggest things that might make the data compress to the left side of the graph when roll values are > 1? I know it is in my code somewhere but I don't know where to look as I have checked the data and the dygraphs call in js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any others who have this problem, I had asked what kinds of things might cause this so I would know what to look for. I found it. I was converting my precision to 2 decimals with .toFixed(2). That converts the data back into a string. So if you have this problem check your data format. The reason it is confusing is that the graph can draw with the numbers presented as strings. But it cannot do the math necessary to calculate rolling averages when the data is strings.

Hope this helps others!

Comment: Glad you figured it out! Classic JavaScript WTF.